# how to compare string with html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to compare a string, may be already in variable, with element taken from DOM?
with element like this

"Something here"

when i call this element with .text() method, i dont just get "Something here", but more like

```
"    
Something 
          here
              "
```

This is not a literal example, i mean my value is returned with additional whitespaces, and therefore i'm not able to compare it with anything, even if i copy whitespaced string from console.

EDIT

Pretty much all answers tell me to use $.trim, i tried it before and it doesnt work, doesnt remove all the whitespaces, still cant compare even with copy/paste from console.log

Answer (score 3):

Trim and Compare:

```
if("string_to_compare" == $.trim(element.text())) {
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use trim() to remove the trailing and leading spaces then compare them..

```
$.trim(x.text()) == 'abc'
```

[$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) is used instead of [String.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) because of [IE support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$.trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to remove the spaces around the text you have.

```
$.trim($("selector").text())
```

> The $.trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including
>   non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the
>   supplied string. If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of
>   the string, they are preserved, [jQuery Doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want a dependency on JQuery, you should instead use a regular expression:

```
"Some String" == element.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

can you specify the version of jquery you're using (+ post your code maybe) ? I've checked a couple  of answers and made my own check and they all seem to work just fine.